# NSAllowsArbitraryLoads does not work in React-Native ios 16.1

Tags: ios, react-native

Currently develop react-native based iOS app, using `axios.post` (contains only username, corporation, email, password) to register an account with backend implemented in `Node.js` with `jwt`, but always get `[AxiosError: Network Error]` in terminal. More specifically, error code is `-1004: "Could not connect to server"`.
[image]

I'm sure API works fine due to I've use Postman to test it.
[image]

I tried to add

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
```

in Info.plist, but not working, still get the same error.

I've also tried the way [axios handling errors docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors) provide to `console.log` error information, and `error.response.data` and `error.response.headers` both show `undefined`, while `error.response.status` shows `0`.

Here is how I fetch data using `axios.post` in react-native:

```
import React, {createContext} from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';
import ApiManager, {BASE_URL} from '../configs/authConfig';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const register = (name, corporation, email, password) => {
    axios
      .post(`${BASE_URL}/auth/register`, {
      name,
      corporation,
      email,
      password,
    })
    .then(res => {
      let userInfo = res.data;
      console.log(userInfo);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.info(e);
      console.log(`register error : ${e}`);
    });
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{register}}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Please tell me if there is any information I can provide. This is my first time ask here. Thx a lot.